# sort to field in mongodb after grouping and pushing

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to display details of a student in order by both `SEM` and `SRN`

I can sort any one of those, but I want both to be sort by ascdending order, so please help me out.

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.MCA2016.aggregate([ { $group:{ _id:{SRN:"$SRN",SEM:"$SEM" ,SGPA:"$SGPA", TAKEN:"$TAKEN"},num:{$sum:1}}},{ $group:{ _id:"$_id.SRN",marks:{$push:{sem:"$_id.SEM",sgpa:"$_id.SGPA" ,taken:"$_id.TAKEN"}} } },{ $project:{ _id:1, marks:1,count:1,"tol":{"$sum":"$marks.taken"}}},{$sort:{"_id":1,"marks.sem":1}}]).pretty()


     "_id" : "01FM16CCA019",
        "marks" : [
                {
                        "sem" : 3,
                        "sgpa" : 7.91,
                        "taken" : 23
                },
                {
                        "sem" : 1,
                        "sgpa" : 7.91,
                        "taken" : 23
                },
                {
                        "sem" : 2,
                        "sgpa" : 7.91,
                        "taken" : 23
                }
        ],
        "tol" : 69
```